# QProcess error when executing sudo command

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qprocess

QProcess is not accepting write method for user password input.

The QProcess classs module in Qt5 accepts command using sudo when piping it to echo "password" , but it is not working when directly executing Linux command with sudo and using QProcess write function to provide the password.

This is what works :

```
    QProcess echo_proc, useradd_proc;
    echo_proc.setStandardOutputProcess(&useradd_proc);
    echo_proc.start("echo " + user_password);
    useradd_proc.start("sudo -S useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/" + user_name + " -p  $1$y9q3lX76$SWpK59xObYQB.8rIUwWbj0" + " " + user_name);
    echo_proc.waitForFinished(5000);
    useradd_proc.waitForFinished(5000);
```

But if the write method is used to provide the user password then the QProcess is not working.

```
    QProcess useradd_proc;
    useradd_proc.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << " sudo -S useradd -m /home/" << username << " " << " -p " << password << " " << username);
    useradd_proc.waitForStarted(5000);
    useradd_proc.write(password.toStdString().c_str());
    if(!useradd_proc.waitForFinished(5000)) {
        qDebug() << "useradd process failed to finish ...";
        useradd_proc.kill();
        return false;
    }
```

The output of the problematic scenario is the next :

useradd process failed to finish ...

QProcess: Destroyed while process ("bash") is still running.

Comment: probably failing due to lack of tty: https://www.shell-tips.com/2014/09/08/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo/. Look up "setuid" for how to do this the proper way without `sudo`

Comment: I could also add a entry for NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers file but I believe this is not the right way for doing it.